# Why do I get "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values" error when using "feval" function?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a function in matlabthat uses Euler's method for solving IVP's. My code for the function is:

```
function err = EulerIvp(f,fe, h, y0,start, stop)
w = y0;
j = 1;
for i = start:h:stop
    err(j) = abs(w - feval(fe, i));
    disp(err);
    j = j + 1;
    w = w + h.*feval(f, w);
end
```

and my other code is

```
clear;
clc;
fa = @(y) y(2-y);
fb = @(y) y^2 - (y^3)/3 + 1;
h1 = 0.1;
errb1 = EulerIvp(fa, fb, h1, 1, 0, 10);
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in HW6_1>@(y)y(2-y) (line 4)
fa = @(y) y(2-y);

Error in EulerIvp (line 8)
        w = w + h.*feval(f, w);

Error in HW6_1 (line 7)
errb1 = EulerIvp(fa, fb, h1, 1, 0, 10);
```

I think my code is right, but I don't know why I keep getting this error

Comment: You are missing a multiply operator.  Should be y*(2-y)

Comment: That solved it. Sometimes it's the little things. Thank you!